# ReferenceError by script nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm receiving the following error:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"
```

From this code:

```
const cheerioReq = require("cheerio-req");

//noinspection JSAnnotator
cheerioReq("https://my.alpinegqs.com/", (err, $) = {
  console:log($(".header h1").text()),

});
```

Comment: Seems like a typographical error as you've missed the `>`, flagged to close. Assuming that it was just a mistake.

Answer (score -1):

you missed an arrow. try this:

```
const cheerioReq = require("cheerio-req");

//noinspection JSAnnotator
cheerioReq("https://my.alpinegqs.com/", (err, $) => {
  console.log($(".header h1").text()),

});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const cheerioReq = require("cheerio-req");

//noinspection JSAnnotator
cheerioReq("https://my.alpinegqs.com/", (err, $) => {
  console:log($(".header h1").text()),

});
```

Is that supposed to be an arrow function? After `(err, $) =` you need a >

Comment: Only on StackOverflow can you get down-voted for giving the correct answer!! #unbelievable